# VPN SBS2008 cannot connect

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2008

I've got a SBS 2008 server that is setup and running great. Exchange works, fileserver everything a ok. VPN also runs but.. nobody is able to connect to it.

The router is a WRT54G from Linksys. It has VPN passthrough enabled. Port 1179 is forwarded to the server. When the build in client off Vista connects, it quits on "checking user and pass" with error 619.

In the log (on the server) it says: "The following error had occoured in the module for the point to the point protocol on port VPN2-127, username: XXXX. The RADIUS-(dutchword) kenmerk, Tunnel Type for this user is incorrect.

The error ID is: 20255, source: RemoteAccesss.

Anybody who knows what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port for vpn pptp is 1719 not 1179.
You don't need the radius server. Maybe there is a problem there?

Comment: You were correct! The NPC policy for VPN had Radius requirements. Deleted those and YIHAAA! Connected right away! THANK YOU! Damm, how could I miss that!